# pdfmake how to add more than one element in a column

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, makepdf

I'm trying to generate pdf files using [pdf make](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted). But when I define a column I can't add more than one element to that column. I want to add a table and a separate text. But text doesn't appear in the generated pdf file.

This is my code.

```
columns: [
              {
                text: `Timesheet${timesheet}\n`
              },
              {
                text: `Rate${rate}\n\n`
              },
              {
                text: "Amount Due",
                table: {
                  body: xyz
                }
              }
            ]
```

Here table appears but the text **Amount Due** doesn't appear.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set an array of objects inside the column (instead of an object of objects) as follows:

```
columns: [
              {
                text: `Timesheet${timesheet}\n`
              },
              {
                text: `Rate${rate}\n\n`
              },
              [
                {text: "Amount Due"},
                {table: {
                  body: xyz
                }}
              ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `stack`, that will allow you to add multiple elements in the same column.

```
var dd = {
content: [
    {
        columns: [
          {
            text: `Timesheet\n`
          },
          {
            text: `Rate\n\n`
          },
          {
            stack: [
                {text: "Amount Due"},
                {table: {
                    body: [
                        ["one", "two"],
                        ["three", "four"]
                        ]
                }}
            ]
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

}